# Make images proportional to size of screen and in a vertical line?

Tags: html, css

I made a landing page for a small project that I'm working on (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y5o1343j/2/) and I was wondering how to make the images appear smaller and in a line when the browser window is a certain width (especially on mobile).

Here is my HTML:

```
<h1 class="main-title">

    <img id="1" src="img/2-login.png" 
        height="200px" width="150px">

    <img id="2" src="img/logo.png">

    <img id="3" src="img/3-register.png"  
        height="200px" width="150px">

</h1>
```

For example: if viewing on mobile, the images should appear proportional to the width/ height of the screen and be aligned vertically like so:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

When I view my page in a mobile browser, the main logo image appears to be way too large in proportion to the rest of the screen.

This only works in my desktop browser window when I rescale it.

As I resize the browser screen however, this happens:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How can I prevent from the centre image from being on the same line as the first image when the screen size gets to a certain width?

EDIT:

CSS Rules I added:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      #1,#2,#3{
          display:block;
          width:100%;
  }

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

      #1,#2,#3{
          display:block;
          width:100%;
  }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

      #1,#2,#3{
          display:block;
          width:100%;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use media queries:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 568px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait) {
      #1,#2,#3{
          display:block;
          width:100%;
  }
}
```

The media query I've written is fro the iPhone 5 on portrait orientation. The idea to achieve what you want is to set your boxes of content to `display:block` while having a `width:100%`. Don't add any `height` or you might have weird scales on your images.

Comment: I've just tried adding this to the CSS along with `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">` however I'm not getting the result I was after. I've also added a live-page link to the main question ( at the bottom ) if that helps.

Comment: This rule applies if and only if the view port (screen) has between 320px and 568px. Here is a list of other media queries, targeting other devices: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: I've just updated my CSS (see edit on main question) to fit the page to an iPhone 4S (what I'm using to test the mobile site) and I get this: http://imgur.com/IYXj2Bk which I don't think has changed from what I had before, without the media queries.

Comment: Can you try this one: `@media only screen and (max-width: 1039px){
 #1,#2,#3{
          display:block;
          width:100%;
  }
}`

Comment: No change I'm afraid :\

Comment: The plan B would be to add `<br/>` after your image `#1` and your `#2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95060/discussion-between-parab-olah-and-sirsince1990).

Comment: I seem to have found a fix! By changing the following meta tag: `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale="1" name="viewport">` to `initial-scale="0.45"`, the images were perfectly aligned for the screen with appropriate sizes

Comment: This doesn't however fix the problem for other mobile devices. I'm not sure why the @media doesn't seem to work